# What size wire and type to run a 100ft span from a 200amp ranch panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I live in Douglas County,Oregon Im installing a new 200amp ranch panel. I need  to then go from the ranch panel 100ft overhead to an rainproof outside service panel. What size & type wire can I use and any other information that I might need. I have 26ft poles to use for my height.

Comment: How much power do you expect the outside service panel to use? What size breaker will be on the feeder to that panel?

Comment: Over head you will need to go with aluminum because of the weight. How many poles do you have for the run ?  What type poles?  Are there any driveways that will be crossed?

Comment: 100' isn't quite far enough for voltage drop to be a problem.  200A *service* to a dwelling can use 166A wire.  4/0 aluminum will do the job underground or pole line. You're allowed to use smaller on a pole line, but voltage drop might start to become an issue if you do. Nothing wrong with aluminum at large sizes and nobody uses copper overhead (except trolley contact wires, for wear).

Comment: Poles will probably have to be down guyed.

Comment: What are you trying to provide power to?